# getting an error from apt-get autoremove

Tags: apt

I am running out of space on my hardisk. I tried running apt-get autoremove but am getting an error:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for richb201: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 504 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: aws_access_key_id: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/richb201/Vault"
CI_ENV="development"
aws_access_key_id = 4WOT
aws_secret_access_key = 2E/oe1k
```

Comment: `autoremove` rarely frees much space. The installed system tends to be quite small.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what added lines

```
aws_access_key_id = 4WOT
aws_secret_access_key = 2E/oe1k
```

in **/etc/environment** but I suppose they should be written without spaces, so you could try editing the file as superuser and then retry autoremoving.